# Accessing objects in 2D arrays?

Tags: java, oop

I want to print out the "weight" of an item in my game.

Class, "Item":

```
public class Item {

private String name;
private double weight;

public Item(String n, double w)
{
    this.name = n;
    this.weight = w;
}
```

}

In the main class I have this bit of code:

```
 public static Item[][] items = {{new Item("Dagger", 1), new Item("Sword", 5), new Item("Bullet(s)", 0), new Item("Pistol", 15)},
                               {new Item("Torch", 2), new Item("Shovel", 5), new Item("Pickaxe", 10)},
                               {new Item("Gold", 0), new Item("Potion(s)", 1)}};
```

How could I print the weight of dagger, for example?

Comment: First of all, your `Item` class is incomplete. There is no "getter" or "accessor" method to your class data members. So, how do you expect to print out their values?  Second of all, you show no attempt to iterate through the array. So I am not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something,

```
System.out.println(items[0][0].getWeight());
```

Of course, your `Item` class will need to be modified to include accessors since the fields are private (which is the recommended approach). I suggest you also make your fields `final` so the class instances are immutable. I would also override `toString()` like

```
public class Item {
    private final String name;
    private final double weight;

    public Item(String n, double w) {
        this.name = n;
        this.weight = w;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s %.3f", name, weight);
    }
}
```

The advantage of overriding `toString()` is you could also use [`Arrays.deepToString(Object[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object[]%29) like

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(items));
```

and get meaningful results printing the entire array.

Comment: items[0] would return an array of Item

Comment: thanks, can you explain why those fields are supposed to be private(as opposed to being public)? Like you stated.

Comment: @Arman [**Encapsulation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) from the Wikipedia  is one (or both) of *A language mechanism for restricting access to some of the object's components.* and *A language construct that facilitates the bundling of data with the methods (or other functions) operating on that data.*

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need a getter in your Item class for weight since weight is declared private. So if you added the following method to Item:

```
    Public Double GetWeight()
    {
        return this.weight;
    }
```

Then you could access Daggar like the following:

```
    Double weight = items[0][0].GetWeight();
    system.out.println(weight);
```

Comment: That was very nice of you Maxqueue. The point of this site is to help people through problems, not to solve the problems for them.